# Set with custom rule

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

According to the [Set doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html), elements in a set are compared using `eql?`.

I have a class like:

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :bar, :baz

  def initialize(bar = 1, baz = 2)
    @bar = bar
    @baz = baz
  end

  def eql?(foo)
    bar == foo.bar && baz == foo.baz
  end
end
```

In console:

```
f1 = Foo.new
f2 = Foo.new
f1.eql? f2 #=> true
```

But...

```
 s = Set.new
 s << f1
 s << f2
 s.size #=> 2
```

Because `f1` equals `f2`, `s` should **not** include both of them.

How to make the `set` reject elements with a custom rule?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The docs that you link to say explicitly (emphasis mine):

> The equality of each couple of elements is determined according to `Object#eql?`
>   **and `Object#hash`**, since `Set` uses `Hash` as storage.

If you add a `hash` method to your class that returns the same value for `eql?` objects, it works:

```
# With your current class

f1, f2 = Foo.new, Foo.new
p f1.eql?(f2)
#=> true
p f1.hash==f2.hash
#=> false
p Set[f1,f2].length
#=> 2

# Fix the problem
class Foo
  def hash
    [bar,hash].hash
  end
end

f1, f2 = Foo.new, Foo.new
p f1.eql?(f2)
#=> true
p f1.hash==f2.hash
#=> true
p Set[f1,f2].length
#=> 1
```

*To be honest I've never had a great sense for how to write a **good** custom `hash` method when multiple values are involved.*

Comment: Can't you just use `[bar, baz].hash` as a hash?

Comment: ok got it, seems like I completely misunderstood `hash`... silly me :) Thanks for  your clear answer!

Comment: @MladenJablanović That seems like a **much** better strategy. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to the The Ruby Programming Language book (co-authored by Yukihiro Matsumoto, Ruby language creator) general-purpose recipe for hash method involves some numeric (17/37) constants usage. For given example suggested solution would be like:

```
def hash
  code = 17
  code = 37*code + @bar.hash
  code = 37*code + @baz.hash
  code
end
```

So in general we're repeating "code = 37*code + @x.hash" line for each significant instance variable (@x).

Comment: btw: it's mentioned that this approach is adapted from the book Effective Java by Joshua Bloch (Prentice Hall)